# Установление униформы для нескольких программ

Tags: opengles

У меня есть пул программ, которые я использую для отрисовки некоторой сцены. При этом мне нужно для каждой программы установить один параметр в качестве униформы (матрица преобразования из координат сцены в `ndc`). Этот параметр нужно задать всего один раз (при условии что сцена не изменяется в размерах) и для этого я пробегаюсь по пулу программ, вызываю `glUseProgram` для каждой проги и устанавливаю соответствующую юниформу (у всех шэйдоров она присутствует). Так вот, насколько это безопасно? После изменения текущей проги значения униформ обязательно сохраняются или они могут инвалидироваться?

Comment: если Вы компилируете шейдеры в рантайм и ресайз редкая операция, то можно вообще избавится от этой uniform и превратить её в const, пересобирая шейдер каждый раз при ресайзе

Comment: @StrangerintheQ нет, это не настолько редкая операция

Comment: хотя и установка в каждом кадре убранная за `if (prevSize != currentSize)` вряд ли скажется на производительности =)

Comment: и да, отвечая на Ваш вопрос - значения uniform сохранятся между переключениями программ

Comment: вот тут достаточно все подробно https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Uniform_(GLSL)